# Can’t move data in ExecuteInEditMode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to move all button data to another one and put it in `Start()`, it work.
like this:

```
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allanimal.Length; i++)
    {
        allanimal[i].GetComponent<cat>().bodypart= BasebodyManager.singleton.ButtonStore[i].GetComponent<dog>().bodypart;
    }
}
```

But when i put it in `[ExecuteInEditMode]` and try to edit it in editor, I get this:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

someone say :"Unity is not serializing my class"

so i can't move all button data to another one use `[ExecuteInEditMode]`?

Comment: Try using this.runInEditMode = true;

Comment: is your BasebodyManager also running in edit mode? it might be worth checking if result of GetComponent<cat> is not null before proceeding